# Convert netbeans project to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, java-me, eclipseme

I have developed one j2me application using netbeans. And now for some reasons i want to convert it into eclipse project. I have installed plugin `EclipseME` in eclipse. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the [sun java toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) or [Java ME SDK 3.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html) and then integrate with Eclipse.

Go to the file and select the import option. import window open on the screen. Here expand the Java ME and open the Netbeans Project. Select the netbeans project root directory and click the finish button. It automatically convert netbeans project to eclipse project.

**File -> import -> Java ME -> Netbeans Project -> netbeans project root directory -> finish**

Comment: After selecting the netbeans project in root directory,it's not showing any j2me,java,web applications...it's just showing one simple application..

Comment: Yeah i have installed these 2 `sun java toolkit and Java ME SDK 3.0` how to integrate?

Comment: **windows -> preferences -> Java ME -> device Management -> Manually install -> select installed toolkit sdk directory -> finish**

Comment: Ya,I had done it already,But when i import it's not showing j2me,web applications..

Comment: Can you tell me flow for creating the project in eclipse?